# Big-O algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrbfq.jpg)

Can anyone tell me answer for this algorithm?

I Think the answer is O(nlogn) but i’m not confident with my answer

Comment: I think it's still O(n^2), like optimised bubble sort

Comment: Please post code as text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: Imagine the loops printing `*` in a triangle shape, one more `*` in each line. The area of the triangle (number of `*`) corresponds to the number of iterations of the inner loop, and thus the complexity. And the area of a triangle is (w*h)/2, i.e. 0.5n², i.e. O(n²).

Answer (score 2):

it will be n^2.
as the loop give complexity of n.
and loop are nested so its n*n=n^2.